# JIRA, Third party SSL, Redirect on CentOS

Tags: tomcat, ssl, jira

I have the following situation:

1. JIRA installed on a VPS (CentOS 5)
2. I am able to access jira at http://www.example.com:8080
3. Third party SSL installed on https:/www.example.com
4. A subdomain http://jira.example.com

What I want to do is the following:

a. To redirect all http to https
b. JIRA (on 8080) to work on https
c. jira.example.com to redirect to https://www.example.com:8080

I can achieve (a) but fail with (b) and (c) although I have followed Atlassian's guide.

This is the code for the connector in server.xml

```
    <Connector port="8080"

               maxThreads="150"
               minSpareThreads="25"
               connectionTimeout="20000"

               enableLookups="false"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
               redirectPort="8443"
               acceptCount="100"
               disableUploadTimeout="true"

               scheme="https" 
               proxyName="jira.example.com" 
               proxyPort="443" 
               secure="true"

                />
```

What I haven't figured out is how to configure the virtual host. Do I need VH for port 443? or 80 (for jira.example.com)

I have read a guide from Atlassian about how to use SSL but that guide generates a CSR and then acquires the SSL. I now have my SSL, so how can I use it? I don't have the required files as shown in the guide.

This is my VH code (taken from jira docs):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName jira.example.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyVia Block
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / https://www.example.com:8080/     <--- If https works
   ProxyPassReverse / https://www.example.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you already have Apache in place working as a reverse proxy, you should use that to proxy all requests to Jira and let it handle SSL/TLS. For this to work though, you will have to check what domains are included in your certificate:

a) Your certificate includes jira.example.com in the SAN field. In this case, your configuration would look like this:

server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080"

           maxThreads="150"
           minSpareThreads="25"
           connectionTimeout="20000"

           enableLookups="false"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
           redirectPort="8443"
           acceptCount="100"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"

           scheme="https" 
           proxyName="jira.example.com" 
           proxyPort="443"

/>
```

vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jira.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jira/htdocs
    RewriteEngine On
    # strip Proxy header to mitigate CGI vuln (https://httpoxy.org)
    RequestHeader unset Proxy
    RewriteRule /(.*) https://jira.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L,NC,NE]

    CustomLog /var/www/jira/logs/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/jira/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCompression off
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/jira.example.com.crt.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/jira.example.com.key.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/jira.example.com.crt_intermediate.pem


    ServerName jira.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jira/htdocs

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
    # strip Proxy header to mitigate CGI vuln (https://httpoxy.org)
    RequestHeader unset Proxy

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^jira.example.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://jira.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L,NC,NE]

    CustomLog /var/www/jira/logs/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/jira/logs/error.log

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will proxy all requests in Apache and forward them to Jira when accessing jira.example.com. It will also redirect you to https when accessing jira.example.com over plain http.

b) Your certificate only includes www.example.com. In this case, you will have to access jira via e.g. www.example.com/jira

server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080"

           maxThreads="150"
           minSpareThreads="25"
           connectionTimeout="20000"

           enableLookups="false"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
           redirectPort="8443"
           acceptCount="100"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"

           scheme="https" 
           proxyName="www.example.com" 
           proxyPort="443"

/>

[...]

<Context path="/jira" docBase="../jira" debug="0" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
```

That last part is important there for Jira to generate correct links.

vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www..example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jira/htdocs
    RewriteEngine On
    # strip Proxy header to mitigate CGI vuln (https://httpoxy.org)
    RequestHeader unset Proxy
    RewriteRule /(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L,NC,NE]

    CustomLog /var/www/jira/logs/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/jira/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCompression off
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.com.crt.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.com.key.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.com.crt_intermediate.pem


    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jira/htdocs

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
    # strip Proxy header to mitigate CGI vuln (https://httpoxy.org)
    RequestHeader unset Proxy

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L,NC,NE]

    CustomLog /var/www/jira/logs/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/jira/logs/error.log

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /jira http://127.0.0.1:8080/jira
    ProxyPassReverse /jira http://127.0.0.1:8080/jira
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

This setup has the advantage that you do not need to configure your certificate in Jira but can instead do all the SSL stuff in Apache.